# What does "subject to" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm reading a book and found this sentence.

> Bitcask offers high-performance reads and writes, subject to the
>   requirement that all the keys fit in the available RAM, since the hash
>   map is kept completely in memory.

I don't quite understand the meaning of **subject to** in it. I looked it up in the dictionary, but I still not sure I understood. In the example sentence, does it mean **Bitcast does meet the requirement that all the keys fit in the available RAM**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this context, ***subject to*** is stating a requirement which must be met for the "high-performance reads and writes" to be achieved; in this way, the phrase ***subject to the requirement*** would be synonymous with ***providing***, e.g.:

> Bitcask offers high-performance reads and writes, **providing** that all the keys fit in the available RAM, since the hash map is kept completely in memory.

Refer to [definition (3) on Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subject%20to):

> **subject to** (phrasal verb)  : dependent on something else to happen or be true
>   - *The sale of the property is subject to approval by the city council*.
>   - *All rooms are just $100 a night, subject to availability*.

Comment: +1 Another simpler synonymous phrase would be **only if** all keys fit in available a RAM.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Good alternative!

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I don't understand "in available a RAM".

Comment: "As long as" is my preferred replacement.

Comment: @Lee Mac, sorry, typo. "in available RAM".